# Option Tree gallery image doesn't showing

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using [Option tree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) wordpress plugin for my wordpress theme. I have a custom field called 'post_gallery'. I am using the custom field for [multiple image attachment](http://prntscr.com/3gkdwx) to make a slideshow in post.

Normally I do echo of the custom filed to show the value. but this time the images are not showing. Please help me that how can I show all the images.
Below the codes which I am using.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_gallery', true); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, 10 months later here is the answer :)

Comment: Hi, 10 months later here is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) ) {
$images = explode( ',', ot_get_option( 'your_id', '' ) );
    if ( ! empty( $images ) ) {
foreach( $images as $id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $id ) ) {
$full_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, '' );
    echo '<li><img src="' . $full_img_src . '"/></li>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

?>

I hope it helps.

Here is more detailed docs on this :
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z25c8S9RnHE
- http://webdgallery.com/option-tree-framework-type-gallery-wordpress/